# error detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, imageai

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()
detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path ,    "image.webp"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpg"))
for eachObject in detections:
print(eachObject\["name"\] + " : " + eachObject\["percentage_probability"\] )
```

Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid path, path not pointing to a valid file.
File "D:\NHANDIENGUONGMAT\ObjectDetection.py", line 7, in 
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
ValueError: invalid path, path not pointing to a valid file.